# C# How to communicate with a running process via deep links?

Tags: c#, .net, deep-linking

I have a windows desktop app (3rd party, closed source) with a C# plugin environment that I can write plugins to.

I also have a web app that I am developing.

I would like to make it possible for the two to communicate using deep links - e.g clicking on a certain button in the web app will trigger an action in the desktop app.

I read about deep links but it seems they require modifying the desktop app manifest, which I don't think I can because I can only write plugins for the desktop app.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?
I can write an additional desktop app (which I have full control of, and therefore can edit its manifest) to handle the deep link handling, and use IPC to communicate with the plugin running in the 3rd party app. But is there a more elegant way?